# Trying to add a menu page into WordPress admin site

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to add a menu page to my admin site, as well as add a footer to Word Press site. However, nothing shows up. There is not an error message. I copied this code from YouTube, apparently the code worked for the guy who was doing the tutorial, but not for me.

I installed it and nothing shows up. Please help!

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
    /**
    * Plugin Name: SBESS
    * Plugin URI: sbess.ca
    * Description: This plugin is to modify the email address of the current website.
    * Version: 1.0.0
    * Author: Rihao Kang
    * Author URI: sbess.ca
    * License: GPL2
    */

    ?>


    <?php
    // put the footer message into database
    function sbess_install(){
        add_option ('sbess_powerby', 'What..sup');

    }


    function sbess_deactive(){
        delete_option ('sbess_powerby');

    }

    function sbess_footer(){
        echo'<center>'.get_option('sbess_powerby').'</center>';

    }

    function sbess_menu(){

    //title of the webpage the when the title is clicked
    //actually text when it is used for the link
    //detect the perticular the user can access the menu
    //unique name provided for this particular menu, identify the menu
        add_menu_page('sbess','sbess','manage_option','sbessmenu','sbess_main_page');
    }

    function sbess_main_page(){

        echo'<h2>SBESS</h2>Welcome to SBESS ';
    }


// activation of the o
    register_activation_hook (_File, 'sbess_install');
    register_deactivation_hook (_File, 'sbess_deactive');
    add_action ('wp_footer','sbess_footer');
    add_action('admin_menu','sbess_menu');

    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting. Would you please include a link to the YouTube video in your post.

Comment: This is unrelated to the answer itself - you shouldn't be using `<center>` tags. Set the `text-align` property to `center` in CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you've taken is correct and the issue you're having comes down to a simple typo.

One of the arguments for `add_menu_page()` is capability and the value correct value is `manage_options` whereas in your code you have it as `manage_option`.

```
add_menu_page( 'sbess', 'sbess', 'manage_options', 'sbessmenu', 'sbess_main_page' );
```

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Also for the activation and deactivation hooks the first argument needs to be changed from `_File` to `__FILE__`.